# Research or studies on rapid skill acquisition?

Tags: learning, perceptual-learning

Are there anything studies or research in psychology and neuroscience currently on the rapid acquisition of skills to an expert level?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Have a look at Hambrick et al 2016 beyond born vs made. And McNamara et al 2014 - Deliberate Practice and Performance in music etc

Comment: Can you expand your question; what do you mean with 'expert'? What is 'rapid' (hours of learning time? Life years?)? Have you done any prior research? What did you find?

Comment: Thanks Nick H! Hey AliceD. Talking about hours of practice. I've read Anders Ericcsson handbook on expertise and his book peak.

Comment: The question is regarding becoming an expert in less time than it requires the average person to reach expertise in a field.